# what is the right functional way to iterate over a Flux of N elements twice with Spring WebFlux library without hitting the db twice?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm new to Spring Reactor, and I'm not sure what is the right way to do the following:

I have two reactive repository of type MyEntity and SumEntity, repo and sumRepo.

I need to do the following in one method, method A:

```
 Flux<MyEntity> entities = repo.findAll();
 entities.map(e -> e.getAmount).reduce(0,Integer::sum).flatMap(sum -> {
    SumEntity sumEntity = createSumEntity(sum);
    return sumRepo.save(sumEntity);

})
```

after the sum is calculated, **I want to iterate again over the same entities**(which are in memory right now?) and do more processing in another method, method B which accepts Flux<MyEntity> as an argument and to do something like:

```
entities.flapMap(ele -> {
   ele.setUsable(false);
   return repo.save(ele); 
})
```

What is the right way to do so? doing as is would trigger another db query for repo db, right? I don't want that.

I can add each emitted MyEntity to a List and then do Flux.fromIterable() and pass the result to method B, but it feels not fully reactive... there's a cache() method to Flux, but im not sure how to use it.

10x for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this. One of the ways i can think of is you can chain your functions with `.and()` method like below.

```
Flux<MyEntity> entities = repo.findAll();
 entities.map(e -> e.getAmount).reduce(0,Integer::sum).flatMap(sum -> {
    SumEntity sumEntity = createSumEntity(sum);
    return sumRepo.save(sumEntity);

}).and(
entities.flapMap(ele -> {
   ele.setUsable(false);
   return repo.save(ele); 
}));
```

Comment: i cant find an `and` function in the Flux api https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html

Comment: reduce method returns a Mono and flatmap on a Mono also returns a Mono, so first reactive func inturn returns a mono. 
So to chain the next reactive call, i suggested to use and() method which is present on Mono.
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#reduce-A-java.util.function.BiFunction-
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#and-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-

Comment: Do you have a use case which is specific to flux?

Comment: i missed the reduce, so thought the operation was being done on a Flux. My bad